# lambda expression for traversing through an array

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda

i'm a lambda noob

i am looking for a way using anonymous methods to sum up the result of a count variable 
in my items

```
class SomeObject
{
    public int Count{get;}
}

SomeObject [] items = new SomeObject[]{......};
```

i am looking for a lambda expression to sum up and return the Amount of all the Counts
something along the lines of

```
Func<SomeObject[],int> counter =  // the lambada i don't know how to write.
```

appreciate any help and references to some good tutorials

i wan't to post another dilemma the extensions are all good an nice 
but what if i'm required to perform a process which is not built in for the collection 
like Sum , Where , Select ...ext.

for example :

```
     string description = string.empty; 
     foreach(var provider in Providers)
     {
            description += provider.Description ;
     }
     return decapitation .
```

iv'e encapsulated it in a Func delegate but i'm required to reference that delegate toan anonymous method using lambda expression which preforms the code above , i just can't figure out the syntax for doing so .

in general i am looking for a way to write a foreach loop with it's logic inside using a lambda expression

(fyi the code is exemplary and as no real use).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
var sum = items.Sum(i => i.Count);
```

[`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345537.aspx) is an extension method provided by LINQ which sums an enumerable sequence of items. In this case, since the items (which are of type `SomeObject`) cannot be summed themselves, you want to use the overload of `Sum` that accepts a lambda. This lambda serves to extract the "summable" value from each item.

In this case, the "summable" value is the `Count` of each `SomeObject`, hence `i => i.Count`.

Comment: this is only good for Generic collections 
i'm using an Array it does not have thous extensions

Comment: @eranotzer: In your example we see a typed array for which these extension methods [do apply](http://www.ideone.com/5J2nf) (of course you need to do `using System.Linq`). If what you have is not exactly what you posted, please edit the question.

Comment: An array *is* a generic collection: SomeObject[] is one possible instance of IEnumerable<SomeObject>. If it doesn't work for you, it's because you're not referencing the right namespace. "using System.Linq;" should be enough to get it working.

Comment: ok , thanks 
i didn't think of adding the LINQ namespace
it works now .

Comment: hi @Jon 
while where on the subject maybe you could help me out with a little something. (look at the post again )

Comment: @eranotzer: It would be better if you asked a separate question for this.